# My JNI JPEG encoder for Android is really slow

Tags: android, optimization, java-native-interface, jpeg, profile

I'm working on a little Android app to stream some camera footage (as a series of JPEGs) to my computer.  With no processing, the frame buffer receives camera preview images at about 18 fps.  When I add in

```
YuvImage yuv = new YuvImage(data, ImageFormat.NV21, dimensions.width, dimensions.height, null);
yuv.compressToJpeg(new Rect(0, 0, dimensions.width, dimensions.height), 40, out);
```

the frame rate drops to about 7 fps.  So I thought I'd write my own JPEG encoder in C and speed it up a bit.  Well I was in for a surprise.  I'm now getting 0.4 fps!

So now I need to profile and optimize my C code, but I don't really know where to begin.  I'm using these GCC flags:

```
-Wall -std=c99 -ffast-math -O3 -funroll-loops
```

Is there anything I can improve there?

Other than that, my JPEG encoder is just a straight forward implementation.  Write header info, write quantization and Huffman tables, then entropy encode the data.  The DCT is using AA&N's method I believe is the fastest way of doing this.

Perhaps there is a problem with the JNI overhead?

I'm allocating the memory in Java using:

```
frame_buffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(raw_preview_buffer_size).array();
jpeg_buffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(10000000).array();
```

and then pulling it in with this code (pardon the spaghetti at the moment):

```
void Java_com_nechtan_limelight_activities_CameraPreview_handleFrame(JNIEnv* env, jobject this, jbyteArray nv21data, jbyteArray jpeg_buffer) {
    jboolean isCopyNV21;
    jboolean isCopyJPEG;
    int jpeg_size = 0;

    jbyte* nv21databytes = (*env)->GetByteArrayElements(env, nv21data, &isCopyNV21);
    jbyte* jpeg_buffer_bytes = (*env)->GetByteArrayElements(env, jpeg_buffer, &isCopyJPEG);

    if (nv21databytes != NULL) {
        if (jpeg_buffer_bytes != NULL) {
            jpeg_size = compressToJpeg((UCHAR*) nv21databytes, (UCHAR*) jpeg_buffer_bytes, 640, 480);
            (*env)->ReleaseByteArrayElements(env, jpeg_buffer, jpeg_buffer_bytes, 0);
            (*env)->ReleaseByteArrayElements(env, nv21data, nv21databytes, JNI_ABORT);
            }
        else {
            __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_DEBUG, DEBUG_TAG, "JPEG data null!");
            }
        }
    else {
        __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_DEBUG, DEBUG_TAG, "NV21 data null!");
        }

    }
```

Am I doing something inefficient here?  What is a good way to profile JNI code?

Other than those things, the only thing I can think of is that I'm going to have to read about NEON and vectorize this stuff.  Ugh...

Comment: Using a ready made encoder, where someone already did all the sensible optimization, would be the logical first step. Also, decoupling compression from acquisition might be advisable.

Comment: Allocating memory in Java and then using it in native will cause poor performance. You can do memory allocation and file I/O within native code and it will perform much better. I can't comment on your JPEG code because you haven't shared it, but my native JPEG encoder/decoder perform well on Android by keeping everything on the native side.

Comment: @Seva, it's not going to stay JPEG -- it will eventually morph into one of the wavelet encoder for video, but I need a baseline to make sure I'm getting everything optimized correctly

Comment: @BitBank, it's more optimal to reallocate memory on each run of the C code rather than a one time allocation in Java and passing it in?  Or is there a way to make the buffer allocated in C persistent between calls?

Comment: The JNI code is loaded once and it is allowed to have static variables. You can allocate a block of memory and re-use it between calls.

Comment: @BitBank While I'm at it, let me ask, for your app are you still passing a pointer to the preview frame buffer in with each call or did you find a way to access the camera frame buffer directly?

Comment: I haven't worked much with the camera. My app is an image viewer (Fast Image Viewer). If I get some spare time (famous last words), I will investigate image capture.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using the build in encoder:

```
 private byte[] compressYuvToJpeg(final byte[] yuvData) {
    mJpegCompressionBuffer.reset();
    YuvImage yuvImage =
        new YuvImage(yuvData, ImageFormat.NV21, mPreviewWidth, mPreviewHeight, null);
    yuvImage.compressToJpeg(new Rect(0, 0, mPreviewWidth, mPreviewHeight), mJpegQuality,
        mJpegCompressionBuffer);
    return mJpegCompressionBuffer.toByteArray();
  }
```

Comment: At the top of my post, that's actually what I do originally.  It's not fast enough though.  With the 800 MHz processor that my phone has, that's roughly 96 clock cycles per color sample in order to maintain 18 fps.  It should certainly be possible some way or another.

Comment: I suggest to check which function takes up the most computation time, simply by leaving out one ore more functions and measuring the receiving time at the pc side.  Also note there exist a h264 streamer for android, http://code.google.com/p/ipcamera-for-android/